# How do I join two pandas data frames in pandasql using the index?

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, pandasql

I know how to join tables in various ways in pandas - concat, merge, etc.  but I would like to know how to do this using pandasql as well.  Specifically, I'd like to join two pandas data frames on the index.  Is this possible?  When I do

```
new_df = pysqldf("SELECT a.*, b.list3 from df1 as a INNER JOIN df2 as b ON a.key=b.key;")
```

I get the correct result.  (I have a "key" variable on both tables.)  However, when I try

```
new_df = pysqldf("SELECT a.*, b.list3 from df1 as a INNER JOIN df2 as b ON a.index=b.index;")
```

I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PandaSQLException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-ecab230d4dc9> in <module>()
----> 1 new_df = pysqldf("SELECT a.*, b.list3 from df1 as a INNER JOIN df2 as b ON a.index=b.index;")

<ipython-input-100-adc122e97ed8> in <lambda>(q)
      1 from pandasql import sqldf
----> 2 pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

/Users/jwesley/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandasql/sqldf.pyc in sqldf(query, env, db_uri)
    154     >>> sqldf("select avg(x) from df;", locals())
    155     """
--> 156     return PandaSQL(db_uri)(query, env)

/Users/jwesley/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandasql/sqldf.pyc in __call__(self, query, env)
     61                 result = read_sql(query, conn)
     62             except DatabaseError as ex:
---> 63                 raise PandaSQLException(ex)
     64             except ResourceClosedError:
     65                 # query returns nothing

PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "index": syntax error [SQL: 'SELECT a.*, b.list3 from df1 as a INNER JOIN df2 as b ON a.index=b.index;']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just name the index `df1.index.rename('foo', inplace=True)` then you can refer to the index by column named `'foo'` in the sql query.

That's because pandasql will check if the index name is set:

> From https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/blob/a6b7ac405ef741400221600d6769faaf1bdbc6ab/pandasql/sqldf.py#L121
>
> ```
> def write_table(df, tablename, conn):
>     """ Write a dataframe to the database. """
>     with catch_warnings():
>         filterwarnings('ignore',
>                        message='The provided table name \'%s\' is not found exactly as such in the database' % tablename)
>         to_sql(df, name=tablename, con=conn,
>                index=not any(name is None for name in df.index.names))  # load index into db if all levels are named
> ```

Note: I've tried renaming the index to 'index' and the query failed. But it succeeded with other index name set. Maybe 'index' is a [keyword in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)?

Or you can add a new column which is same as the index: `df1['index'] = df1.index`.